# I need to put quotation marks around a property in an object. How do i do that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have something that looks like this: -

```
var array = ["119306.jpg","149426.jpg","157715.jpg","161706.jpg","171278.jpg","172313.jpg","179934.jpg","182047.jpg","182084.jpg","182261.jpg","183351.jpg","185276.jpg","189666.jpg","190304.jpg","191798.jpg","191974.jpg","192231.jpg","194943.jpg","196365.jpg","196596.jpg","197040.jpg","197218.jpg","197821.jpg","198096.jpg","198169.jpg","198195.jpg","198540.jpg","198560.jpg","198957.jpg","199021.jpg","199025.jpg","199035.jpg","199241.jpg","199876.jpg","200377.jpg","200408.jpg","200470.jpg","20084.jpg","201761.jpg","202745.jpg","202791.jpg","203344.jpg","203449.jpg","203516.jpg","203840.jpg","203847.jpg","203920.jpg","203984.jpg","204068.jpg","204098.jpg","204293.jpg","204413.jpg","204573.jpg","20485.jpg","204913.jpg","204966.jpg","205896.jpg","206538.jpg","207335.jpg","207428.jpg","207522.jpg","207530.jpg","207660.jpg","207703.jpg","207919.jpg","208246.jpg","208413.jpg","208417.jpg","208912.jpg","208966.jpg","211059.jpg","211197.jpg","211912.jpg","211964.jpg","212046.jpg","212067.jpg","213313.jpg","213678.jpg","213702.jpg","214494.jpg","215444.jpg","217679.jpg","217878.jpg","218000.jpg","218158.jpg","219261.jpg","219278.jpg","219298.jpg","219315.jpg","219331.jpg","219335.jpg","219381.jpg","219400.jpg","219403.jpg","219434.jpg","219442.jpg","219447.jpg","219493.jpg","219545.jpg","219619.jpg","219689.jpg","219782.jpg","220094.jpg","220103.jpg","220219.jpg","220234.jpg","220238.jpg","220281.jpg","220287.jpg","220333.jpg","220399.jpg","220550.jpg","220829.jpg","221185.jpg","221335.jpg","221345.jpg","221356.jpg","221552.jpg","221672.jpg","22218.jpg","222925.jpg","223949.jpg","224148.jpg","225250.jpg","225422.jpg","225612.jpg","226346.jpg","226358.jpg","226670.jpg","226944.jpg","227155.jpg","227985.jpg","228204.jpg","228368.jpg","229266.jpg","229335.jpg","229362.jpg","229410.jpg","229439.jpg","229479.jpg","229510.jpg","229516.jpg","229525.jpg","229558.jpg","229597.jpg","229683.jpg","229688.jpg","229696.jpg","229729.jpg","229743.jpg","229778.jpg","229783.jpg","229788.jpg","229850.jpg","229888.jpg","229894.jpg","229904.jpg","229952.jpg","230362.jpg","230403.jpg","230734.jpg","230794.jpg","230875.jpg","230887.jpg","231019.jpg","231062.jpg","231120.jpg","231160.jpg","231347.jpg","231842.jpg","231846.jpg","231903.jpg","232096.jpg","232136.jpg","232140.jpg","232142.jpg","232197.jpg","232200.jpg","232417.jpg","233085.jpg","233226.jpg","233513.jpg","233523.jpg","233551.jpg","233606.jpg","233630.jpg","233748.jpg","233947.jpg","234214.jpg","234889.jpg","234943.jpg","234985.jpg","235031.jpg","235330.jpg","235411.jpg","235774.jpg","235839.jpg","236133.jpg","236553.jpg","236569.jpg","236686.jpg","236780.jpg","236959.jpg","236972.jpg","236975.jpg","238184.jpg","238355.jpg","238523.jpg","238541.jpg","238692.jpg","238696.jpg","238713.jpg","238897.jpg","238900.jpg","239128.jpg","239162.jpg","239179.jpg","239272.jpg","239331.jpg","239407.jpg","239492.jpg","239593.jpg","239630.jpg","239681.jpg","240967.jpg","241037.jpg","241043.jpg","241044.jpg","241056.jpg","241057.jpg","241195.jpg","241476.jpg","241548.jpg","241579.jpg","241667.jpg","242016.jpg","242164.jpg","242735.jpg","242845.jpg","242936.jpg","242971.jpg","243024.jpg","243661.jpg","243688.jpg","243736.jpg","243781.jpg","243942.jpg","244286.jpg","244592.jpg","244952.jpg","244956.jpg","245081.jpg","245176.jpg","245188.jpg","245202.jpg","245221.jpg","245243.jpg","245314.jpg","245433.jpg","245437.jpg","245468.jpg","245490.jpg","245711.jpg","245771.jpg","245940.jpg","245952.jpg","246018.jpg","246022.jpg","246043.jpg","246134.jpg","246250.jpg","246402.jpg","246409.jpg","246478.jpg","246485.jpg","246494.jpg","246535.jpg","246574.jpg","246652.jpg","246657.jpg","246794.jpg","246973.jpg","246997.jpg","247081.jpg","247121.jpg","247190.jpg","247319.jpg","247630.jpg","247835.jpg","247852.jpg","247943.jpg","248122.jpg","248123.jpg","248166.jpg","248405.jpg","248406.jpg","248486.jpg","248527.jpg","248564.jpg","248578.jpg","248580.jpg","248614.jpg","248616.jpg","248617.jpg","248701.jpg","248704.jpg","248793.jpg","248861.jpg","249074.jpg","249101.jpg","249116.jpg","249177.jpg","249254.jpg","249342.jpg","249407.jpg","249421.jpg","249522.jpg","249531.jpg","249572.jpg","249713.jpg","249884.jpg","249947.jpg","250053.jpg","250087.jpg","250100.jpg","250237.jpg","250298.jpg","250346.jpg","250361.jpg","250375.jpg","250413.jpg","250439.jpg","250493.jpg","250538.jpg","250600.jpg","250660.jpg","250761.jpg","250769.jpg","250774.jpg","250775.jpg","250780.jpg","250785.jpg","250834.jpg","250890.jpg","250948.jpg","250968.jpg","251001.jpg","251004.jpg","251036.jpg","251052.jpg","251054.jpg","251055.jpg","251133.jpg","251148.jpg","251165.jpg","251216.jpg","251219.jpg","251265.jpg","251306.jpg","251371.jpg","251403.jpg","251420.jpg","251451.jpg","251547.jpg","251599.jpg","251680.jpg","251740.jpg","251778.jpg","251837.jpg","251874.jpg","251908.jpg","252002.jpg","252033.jpg","252036.jpg","252060.jpg","252062.jpg","252079.jpg","252084.jpg","252095.jpg","252105.jpg","252172.jpg","252175.jpg","252176.jpg","252179.jpg","252269.jpg","252285.jpg","252343.jpg","252356.jpg","252360.jpg","252366.jpg","252367.jpg","252457.jpg","252470.jpg","252493.jpg","252497.jpg","252531.jpg","252535.jpg","252563.jpg","252571.jpg","252581.jpg","252584.jpg","252646.jpg","252663.jpg","252677.jpg","252725.jpg","252731.jpg","252773.jpg","252832.jpg","252842.jpg","252861.jpg","252922.jpg","252954.jpg","252989.jpg","252996.jpg","253035.jpg","253051.jpg","253078.jpg","253101.jpg","253148.jpg","253156.jpg","253158.jpg","253159.jpg","253162.jpg","253166.jpg","253188.jpg","253189.jpg","253192.jpg","253236.jpg","253257.jpg","253271.jpg","253315.jpg","253323.jpg","253331.jpg","253352.jpg","253355.jpg","253374.jpg","253407.jpg","253417.jpg","253420.jpg","253423.jpg","253426.jpg","253447.jpg","253464.jpg","253466.jpg","253468.jpg","253475.jpg","253483.jpg","253484.jpg","253490.jpg","253495.jpg","253515.jpg","253517.jpg","253530.jpg","253534.jpg","253554.jpg","253597.jpg","253601.jpg","253602.jpg","253644.jpg","253654.jpg","253657.jpg","253668.jpg","253684.jpg","253706.jpg","253735.jpg","253744.jpg","253746.jpg","253763.jpg","253770.jpg","253785.jpg","253786.jpg","253796.jpg","253797.jpg","253832.jpg","253848.jpg","253859.jpg","253861.jpg","253863.jpg","253867.jpg","253870.jpg","253871.jpg","253879.jpg","253887.jpg","253894.jpg","253895.jpg","253898.jpg","253901.jpg","253910.jpg","253916.jpg","253920.jpg","253925.jpg","253927.jpg","253956.jpg","253965.jpg","253967.jpg","253968.jpg","253969.jpg","253984.jpg","253987.jpg","253991.jpg","254009.jpg","254023.jpg","254057.jpg","254069.jpg","254076.jpg","254098.jpg","254099.jpg","254100.jpg","254104.jpg","254125.jpg","254126.jpg","254127.jpg","254131.jpg","254144.jpg","254150.jpg","254158.jpg","254175.jpg","254181.jpg","254182.jpg","254184.jpg","254201.jpg","254202.jpg","254207.jpg","254208.jpg","254210.jpg","254217.jpg","254221.jpg","254223.jpg","254239.jpg","254263.jpg","254264.jpg","254265.jpg","254268.jpg","254282.jpg","254289.jpg","254292.jpg","254293.jpg","254296.jpg","254299.jpg","254300.jpg","254302.jpg","254303.jpg","254309.jpg","254312.jpg","254319.jpg","254329.jpg","254342.jpg","254347.jpg","254348.jpg","254351.jpg","254354.jpg","254359.jpg","254363.jpg","254375.jpg","254377.jpg","254378.jpg","254381.jpg","254393.jpg","254403.jpg","254406.jpg","254422.jpg","254424.jpg","254433.jpg","254440.jpg","254441.jpg","254442.jpg","254445.jpg","254453.jpg","254456.jpg","254457.jpg","254458.jpg","254462.jpg","254471.jpg","254478.jpg","254479.jpg","254485.jpg","254489.jpg","254490.jpg","254495.jpg","254505.jpg","254508.jpg","254513.jpg","254514.jpg","254525.jpg","254532.jpg","254534.jpg","254537.jpg","254539.jpg","254541.jpg","254542.jpg","254543.jpg","254558.jpg","254567.jpg","254576.jpg","254585.jpg","254588.jpg","254592.jpg","254593.jpg","254600.jpg","254601.jpg","254604.jpg","254631.jpg","254654.jpg","254659.jpg","254660.jpg","254666.jpg","254692.jpg","254696.jpg","254698.jpg","254702.jpg","254706.jpg","254710.jpg","254711.jpg","254722.jpg","254723.jpg","254726.jpg","254727.jpg","254730.jpg","254737.jpg","254742.jpg","254745.jpg","254748.jpg","254749.jpg","254753.jpg","254758.jpg","254763.jpg","254765.jpg","254771.jpg","254778.jpg","254780.jpg","254793.jpg","254807.jpg","254815.jpg","254817.jpg","254824.jpg","254825.jpg","254829.jpg","254830.jpg","254838.jpg","254840.jpg","254843.jpg","254848.jpg","254858.jpg","254863.jpg","254864.jpg","254869.jpg","254870.jpg","254872.jpg","254884.jpg","254895.jpg","254898.jpg","254899.jpg","254902.jpg","254906.jpg","254909.jpg","254917.jpg","254921.jpg","254923.jpg","254925.jpg","254926.jpg","254930.jpg","254935.jpg","254937.jpg","254945.jpg","254963.jpg","254971.jpg","254992.jpg","255000.jpg","255002.jpg","255005.jpg","255021.jpg","255024.jpg","255038.jpg","255043.jpg","255045.jpg","255047.jpg","255049.jpg","255057.jpg","255060.jpg","255065.jpg","255066.jpg","255070.jpg","255071.jpg","255072.jpg","255098.jpg","255103.jpg","255109.jpg","255122.jpg","255166.jpg","255182.jpg","255200.jpg","255211.jpg","255218.jpg","255239.jpg","255255.jpg","255290.jpg","255311.jpg","255339.jpg","255369.jpg","255397.jpg","255399.jpg","255408.jpg","255412.jpg","255414.jpg","255428.jpg","255429.jpg","255438.jpg","255441.jpg","255448.jpg","255472.jpg","255480.jpg","255483.jpg","255496.jpg","255498.jpg","255526.jpg","255540.jpg","255567.jpg","255571.jpg","255597.jpg","255601.jpg","255605.jpg","255625.jpg","255731.jpg","255741.jpg","255750.jpg","256742.jpg","256859.jpg","257009.jpg","257058.jpg","257240.jpg","257241.jpg","25732.jpg","257524.jpg","257921.jpg","257991.jpg","258298.jpg","258630.jpg","258644.jpg","258652.jpg","258680.jpg","259194.jpg","259368.jpg","259371.jpg","259503.jpg","259513.jpg","260718.jpg","260876.jpg","260881.jpg","260885.jpg","260915.jpg","260975.jpg","261014.jpg","261108.jpg","261272.jpg","261388.jpg","261533.jpg","261651.jpg","261777.jpg","261782.jpg","261829.jpg","261883.jpg","262115.jpg","262252.jpg","262432.jpg","262464.jpg","262698.jpg","262748.jpg","262753.jpg","262907.jpg","263205.jpg","263221.jpg","263340.jpg","263463.jpg","263464.jpg","263488.jpg","263591.jpg","263802.jpg","264166.jpg","264228.jpg","264231.jpg","264588.jpg","265808.jpg","265818.jpg","265834.jpg","265984.jpg","266743.jpg","28057.jpg","32420.jpg","32447.jpg","32464.jpg","34508.jpg","35149.jpg","36177.jpg","40175.jpg"];

var arrayOfObjects = array.map(function(element) {
  return {id: element};
});
```

So now I have the arrayOfObjects that gives me an id for each image. I need to put quotation marks on those id so to have it in a json format like these:-

```
[ { 'id': '119306.jpg' }, { 'id': '149426.jpg' } ]
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: The array elements are already string.

Comment: Hey, but arrayOfObjects returns an id for each .jpg file. That id is not a string. I need to convert that key (id) into a string. thanks. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `{id: 42}` is **exactly** equivalent to `{"id": 42}`, except if occurring in JSON the double quotes around the key are required, but don't worry, `JSON.stringify` will put them there for you.

Comment: thanks Tushar and torazaburo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is working fine. There is no need to change the keys to strings to use the data. In Javascript objects `{id: ''}` works just as well as `{'id': ''}`.

Now if you need a JSON string, you can run

```
JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)
```

and it will turn your whole array of objects into one long string.